# Issue with parsing data (name to image)

Tags: ios, swift

My json response looks like this...

```
{
    "success": 1,
    "TotalRevenue": “123.12 K",
    "Productdata": [
        {
            "product_id": "5",
            "product_name": “abc”
            "product_images": [
                {
                    "id": "938",
                    "image_url": "http://myApp.direct.com/public165_1_image_15",
                    "is_default": "1"
                }

            ]
        }
```

This is how I'm parsing the data...

```
if let projectData = result["Productdata"] as? [[String:Any]] {

 let images = projectData.flatMap({ $0["product_images"] as? [[String: Any]] }).flatMap({ $0 })

let productName = projectData.flatMap({ $0["product_name"] as? String })
self.arrayOfNames = productName
self.arrayOfId = imageIds

}
```

I have extracted the names and assigned them to an array above. Then I take out each name from the array containing all the names like so...

```
                    for names in self.arrayOfNames {
                                DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async
                                    {
                                        self.theNameArray.append(names)

                                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                            self.collectionView.reloadData()
                                        }
                                }
                            }
```

Finally, so that I can get the appropriate name under each image in the colletionview, I am doing this...

I'm not able to figure out how I'll assign `product name` abc to the `id` 938. I tried something like this...

```
cell.recipeImageView.image = self.arrayOfURLImages[indexPath.row]
cell.nameLabel.text = self.arrayOfNames[indexPath.row]
```

In the above 2 lines of code, the first one shows the images. But my issue is the names are not displayed appropriately i.e. the appropriate name for the image is not shown...instead any random name is assigned to any image. How can I get the correct name under the correct image.

Comment: Your question is not clear to me  **how I'll assign product name abc to the id 938**

Comment: hmm..I'll just edit the question...

Comment: **Don't repost questions**. That's the fourth question about almost the same topic. You got suitable answers in the other questions. From those answers it's very easy to parse that particular key, too. Please learn the stuff. And do not use multiple arrays as data source. Use a custom struct or class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Never** use multiple arrays as table/collection view data source. Sue all tutorials which suggest that!

We are talking about an object oriented language so use custom structs, this is the highly recommended way to parse JSON into a data model.

Create two structs `Product` and `ProductImage`

```
struct ProductImage {
    let id : String
    let url : URL
    let isDefault : Bool
}

struct Product {
    let name : String
    let id : String
    var images = [ProductImage]()

    init(name : String, id : String) {
        self.name = name
        self.id = id
    }

    mutating func add(image :ProductImage) {
        images.append(image)
    }
}
```

Create the data source array

```
var productData = [Product]()
```

Parse the data

```
if let projectData = result["Productdata"] as? [[String:Any]] {
    for anItem in projectData {
        guard let name = anItem["product_name"] as? String,
            let id = anItem["product_id"] as? String else { continue }

        var product = Product(name: name, id: id)
        if let images = anItem["product_images"] as? [[String:String]] {
            for image in images {
                guard let imageId = image["id"],
                    let url = image["image_url"],
                    let isDefault = image["is_default"] else { continue }

                let productImage = ProductImage(id: imageId,
                                                url: URL(string: url)!,
                                                isDefault: isDefault == "1")

                product.add(image: productImage)
            }
        }
        productData.append(product)
    }
}
```

Swift 4 introduces built-in JSON en-/decoding which could get rid of almost the entire parsing code.

Comment: If also like the fact that you are not using any `flatMap()`, `map()` or other stuff like this. Author seems to be lacking experience/knowledge in programming, and orienting development through "manual" for loop is recommended rather than "magic black single lines of code". I'll add to "Never use multiple arrays": That it's harder to debug/fix in case of desynchronization between them when two items at same index are meant to be one.

Comment: @vadian Thanks for the answer..it was very helpful..Have given an upvote also...:). Just one more doubt...is using structs like above just a clean and preferred way to parse JSON or does the use of this approach also have other good reasons behind it...

Comment: @User.bw Use struct or classes for your model. Two main reasons: It's easier then to do `myObjectOrStruct.oneOfItsProperty`, rather than `myJSON["oneOfItsPropert"]`. One misspell could break it (while on the other hand, XCode knows the types, etc). Also, a class/struct can interpret values, gives methods, etc. In your case, it's simply easy, but in case of URLs, you may want to add a baseURL if they are only paths, you may want to add properties, compute them, interpret a timestamp into a Date object (more usefull than seconds from epoch...)...

Comment: Ok..@Larme..Thanks...:)

Answer (score 0):

Your model should have products array where every product has images array. So every product will have its name and its images.